# How do I check isPostback in template control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, template-control

I'm using a template control in a web application. At the moment, everything OnLoad is happening even if the page is a postback (understandably). How do I access an isPostback property in this method to run the necessary checks, just as I would if it were a pages code-behind?

Answer (score 2):

You can add code blocks to your markup:

```
<% if (Page.IsPostBack) { %>
  <div> markup </div>
<% } %>
```

Of course, I'm assuming you're asking about adding an `IsPostBack` check in markup. I suppose you could also mean a `CustomControl`. In that case, you can still use `Page.IsPostBack` in your `CustomControl` class.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs args, object source)
{
  if (Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     // stuff that should only happen during POST
  }
}
```